# Horizontal Grid Lines in CListCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I want only Horizontal grid lines in my CListCtrl .I dont want Vertical grid lines ..I used LVS_EX_GRIDLINES but this is displaying both horizontal and vertical grids ..Any way to display only Horizontal grid lines

Comment: I think you'll have to implement custom drawing for you control - derive your own class from CListCtrl and override OnDrawItem (maybe).

Comment: I have derived a class from CListCtrl and have OnNmCustomDraw() inside it but how i will implement only horizontal grid lines means code snippet that can help me out?